# Opening a directory and searching for a pattern in files

Tags: file, perl

My Perl script is supposed to open all the files in a directory and search for a pattern inside them and print the whole line containing the pattern.
Below is the code. The code is unable to open the file.

```
  my $dir = 'dir1/dir2';
    opendir (DIR, $dir) or die $!;
    my @dir = readdir DIR;
    foreach my $item (@dir) {
        open(FILE, "<", "file.txt")
        or die "Can't open < file.txt: $!";
        while($line= <FILE>) {
        print "$line" if $line=~ /pattern/;
    }
    close FILE;
    }
    closedir DIR;
```

Please suggest some way to make it work.

Comment: The [readdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) returns just names, not paths. So when you try to open `file.txt` there is no such thing -- you need to say `"$dir/file.txt"`. Another way is to prepend that to the whole list, so `my @dir = map { "$dir/$_" } readdir DIR;`  and now files in `@dir` have the correct path

Comment: Hmm, if to follow your logic you try to read file.txt in each dir -- but not every file in the directory(-ies). Your description is not matching with logic of your code.

Comment: I am not sure if perl script is compulsory requirement for solving your task. Otherwise you could use find and grep to achieve same result `find /some/dir -exec grep [pattern] {} \; -ls`. This command will search each and every file in directory and sub-directories.

Comment: @PolarBear Can do that, too, but then there's no need for `find` as `grep` has ways to specify what to search, and here it's trivial, `grep [options] PATTERN dir1/dir2/*` where `options` would decide how to present findings

Comment: Just one note: not all versions of grep supported recursive search in sub-directories - find/grep worked for ages and never failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [readdir](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html) returns just names (`file.txt`), not paths (not `dir1/dir2/path.txt`).

So when the program tries to open `$item`<sup>†</sup> it turns out that there is no such a thing -- need to open `"$dir/$item"`. Or, prepend that to every entry in the filelist and then work away with correct paths

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $dir = 'dir1/dir2';

opendir (my $dh, $dir) or die $!;
my @entries = map { "$dir/$_" } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;

foreach my $item (@entries) {
    next if not -f $item;
    open(my $fh, "<", $item) or die "Can't open < $item: $!";

    while(my $line = <$fh>) {
        print $line if $line =~ /pattern/;
    }
    close $fh;
}
```

Note that I skip entries which aren't regular files (`not -f`, see [filetest operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html)), and use [lexical filehandes instead of typeglobs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles) (`my $fh` instead of `FILE`).

Another option for getting lists of entries is [glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) (see [File::Glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/File/Glob.html)), which does return the path:

```
my @entries = glob $dir;  # dir1/dir2/file.txt  (etc)
```

But if you are indeed acquiring the whole filelist ahead, as opposed to reading and processing an item at a time, then you might as well filter it as needed right away, so

```
my @files = grep { -f } glob $dir;
```

where you now have only regular files.

The whole list can be filtered also in the program above of course. Can do it in the `map` itself

```
opendir (my $dh, $dir) or die $!;
my @files = map { -f "$dir/$_" ? "$dir/$_" : () } readdir $dh;
closedir $dh;
```

Here `map` works as a filter as well by a  little trick: An empty list `()`, returned when an entry isn't a plain file, gets flattened in the returned list thus effectively disappearing, so this amounts to not returning anything in that case. Or, chain `grep` to `map` as usual

```
my @files = grep { -f } map { "$dir/$_" } readdir $dh;
```

This does make (yet) another pass over the list, but that is optimized and hardly ever a concern (unless we had *huge* filelists -- what poses problems in its own right -- and were doing this very often).

---

I'd like to also mention that there are good modules for this, as well.

An example with [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny)

```
use Path::Tiny;

my $it = path($dir)->iterator;

while (my $entry = $it->()) { 
    # it omits . and ..
}
```

This is a "lazy" iterator. See docs, and more so for the many other things that this module offers.

---

<sup>†</sup> Instead of that `file.txt`